# border-bottom + rounded corners in a table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to combine in a table rounded corners for td elements and border-bottom for tr elements, to get a tab-like look (I can't change the html structure).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VvdBQ/

Code:

```
table#one {width:100%;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:separate;}
tr {border-bottom:5px solid red;}
td {font-weight:bold;text-align:center;background:blue;border-radius:15px 15px 0 0;border:1px solid green;}
```

My issue (viewed in Chrome):

- with `border-collapse:separate` the corners are correctly rounded but I don't see the bottom border
- with `border-collapse:collapse` it is the opposite

How can I get both the corners and the bottom border correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `border-collapse:separate;` and also move the style all to the `td` you should be able to get what you want with this:

```
td {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    background:blue;
    border-bottom:5px solid red;
    border-top:1px solid green;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/qjLyZ/

Comment: Thx for the reply. It looks better than my initial css, but I still see an issue with the corners (viewing in Chrome). Also, I might want to add spaces between the tds, and for this reason a border applied to the tr would be better.

Comment: You can add the style property on the table `border-spacing:5px;` and that will add spaces between the td (or tabs). What's the issue you see? I'm viewing it in Chrome as well and it looks how you described?

Comment: sorry I was looking at the wrong one. border-spacing would break the bottom red line, that's why I was hoping to use the tr border. I guess I'll have to live with that...

Comment: No prob, and FYI border-spacing doesn't actually separate the bottom red line since its all part of the same element now. I updated my fiddle to show.